# Does an oscillating sequence of zeros satisfies identity theorem (1st version i.e.limit point of zeros)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f(z) be an analytic function in C. Then f is constant (i.e. identically zero) if the zeros of f in C contains the sequence
an ={n,if 4 doesn't divide n &
         1/n ,if 4|n}

Comment: Observe that the sequence $a_k=1/4k$ is a sequence of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

$a_{4n}=\frac 1 {4n} \to 0$. So the zeros of $f$ have a limit point which implies it is a constant (which must be $0$).

Comment: Why we won't consider the divergent case??? i.e.for n doesn't divide n

Comment: If there is one sequence of zeros with a limit point then the function must be a zero identically. Why do I care to look at all zeros? @pankajkumar